# Volume of a divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

One can define the volume of a divisor $D$ by the formula $\displaystyle \limsup_{m \to \infty} \frac{h^0(X, O(mD))}{m^n/n!}$, where $n$ is the dimension of $X$.

For example, see the definition here (a paper that I randomly chose from a google search): http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~mpopa/papers/RVLS.pdf

Does anyone know if there is a geometric meaning to this definition? ("Why volume?") The author says that this is the "top self-intersection" number, but I don't really know what this means, or what it has to do with the concept of volume (on a complex algebraic manifold).

I'm just curious to know.

Edit: probably this contains an answer to my question: http://www.ms.uky.edu/~corso/Purdue_2011/posters/fulger-poster.pdf

Comment: why don't you explain what intuitively means your definition ?

Comment: @user1952009 Because I don't know...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand a bit on msteves answer, depending on how familiar you are with intersection theory, remember $L$ is a (something like) a hypersurface, and if we intersect $n$ hypersurfaces $L_1\cdot L_2\cdots L_n$, the dimension drops one at a time (unless we're very unlucky) and the result is a set of points - we can forget their locations and think of this as a number.

Intersection theory let's us circumnavigate the above "unluckiness." Even though the set-theoretic intersection $L^n = L\cdot L\cdots L$ with itself $n$ times is just $L$, we can still interpret this as a zero-dimensional thing (a number), philosophically by intersection $n$ *different slightly perturbered* copies of $l$ that are not so unlucky.

In the case that $L$ is nef, the volume as you defined turns out to agree with this number. The question remains: why should $L^n$ be related with volume?

One explanation is that a dimension $k$ subvariety can be thought of as a singular $(n-k)$-cycle, and by Poincare duality + de Rham theory these are related to differential $(n-k)$-forms. Keep intersecting your divisor and you go from codimension 1 right down to codimension n, and hence from 1-forms right up to $n$-forms. Another name for an $n$-form is a "volume form" since one integrates it over a volume.

In other words, $L$ can be thought of (under this intersection->singular->de Rham analogy/correspondence) as related to some $1$-form, and $\text{vol}(L)$ is the $n$-form that we get by wedging with itself $n$ times.

Comment: Clarification question: At the end, we are wedging together the 1-forms relating to the n-different perturbations of $L$? (Otherwise we get 0.) (I think also you mean that it is a singular k-cycle. By the way, do you know a reference that shows subvarieties can be triangulated? Shafarevich just deals with the case of a curve.)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36050/embeddings-and-triangulations-of-real-analytic-varieties seems to answer the question, but I'm not sure. To be honest, before reading the post I'm referencing, I didn't actually know that they always *could* be traingulated, and meant my answer more as an analogy between the intersection ring and the cohomology ring (the latter of which is related to forms by de Rham stuff).

Answer (score 10):

If $L$ is a nef line bundle on a smooth projective complex variety $X$ of dimension $n$, then the volume equals the top self-intersection $(L^n)$, which in turn is the integral of the volume form $c_1(L)^n$, hence the name.